# Restructure JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following array:

```
var res = {
    "status": "Success",
    "data": [
        {"assignedTo":"0", "createdDate":"23-07-2013", "count":"2"}, 
        {"assignedTo":"182398", "createdDate":"01-08-2013", "count":"2"},
        {"assignedTo":"182398", "createdDate":"23-07-2013", "count":"2"}, 
        {"assignedTo":"182398", "createdDate":"24-07-2013", "count":"12"}, 
        {"assignedTo":"182398", "createdDate":"22-07-2013", "count":"1"},
        {"assignedTo":"182398", "createdDate":"30-07-2013", "count":"4"},
        {"assignedTo":"182398", "createdDate":"31-07-2013", "count":"19"},
        {"assignedTo":"185271", "createdDate":"24-07-2013", "count":"2"},
        {"assignedTo":"185271", "createdDate":"23-07-2013", "count":"1"}
    ]
}
```

Now I want to make one json array from the above with the value of `data` to another json 
which will be like:

```
[
    {
        key: "0",
        values: [["23-07-2013", 2]]
    },
    {
        key: "182398",
        values: [["01-08-2013", 2],
                 ["23-07-2013", 2],
                 ["24-07-2013", 12],
                 ["22-07-2013", 1],
                 ["30-7-2013", 4],
                 ["31-7-2013", 19]
    },
    {
        key: "185271",
        values: [["24-07-2013", 2],
                 ["23-07-2013", 1]
    }
]
```

I have tried like the following:

```
for (i in res.data) {
    for (k in res.data[i]) {
        time_val += "[" + res.data[i]['createdDate'] + ","
                    + res.data[i]['count'] + "],";
        cumulative_val += '{key:"' + res.data[i]['assignedTo']
                          + '",values:'+time_val+'},';
    }
}
```

Could you please guide me how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your input is not JSON. JavaScript!=JSON. And your code is not PHP.

Comment: you should note that the structure you want to achieve isn't valid JSON... Nor is your input, btw...

Comment: The better way to create JSON in JS is to create an object or array and convert it to JSON with `JSON.stringify`. Building the JSON manually (like you do) is error prone. For example, keys must be in double quotes in JSON, and you have `key:` instead of `"key":` in your string. If you don't want to create JSON at all, but just convert your object into an array of objects, then say so. But that has nothing to do with JSON then. Also, what's the problem with the code you have? Please explain.

Comment: @Felix Its not in grouped and moreover the time_val is showing repeatedly for a particular assignedTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in javascript:

```
var res = {"status":"Success","data":[{"assignedTo":"0","createdDate":"23-07-2013","count":"2"}, 
                               {"assignedTo":"182398","createdDate":"01-08-2013","count":"2"},
                              {"assignedTo":"182398","createdDate":"23-07-2013","count":"2"}, 
                             {"assignedTo":"182398","createdDate":"24-07-2013","count":"12"}, 
                              {"assignedTo":"182398","createdDate":"22-07-2013","count":"1"},
                              {"assignedTo":"182398","createdDate":"30-07-2013","count":"4"},
                              {"assignedTo":"182398","createdDate":"31-07-2013","count":"19"},
                              {"assignedTo":"185271","createdDate":"24-07-2013","count":"2"},
                              {"assignedTo":"185271","createdDate":"23-07-2013","count":"1"}]
}
//Wanted mixed object
var temp = [];
//Store keys, so we do not need to check from temp if key allready exists
var temp_keys = {};
//Loop trough data
for (var i in res.data)
{
    //Check if key is allready stored in object
    if (!temp_keys[res.data[i]['assignedTo']])
    {
        //Store new key, and save it''s position
        temp_keys[res.data[i]['assignedTo']] = temp.length;
        //Create new array element as new object
        temp.push(
            {
                'key' : res.data[i]['assignedTo'],
                'values': []
            }
        );
    }
    //Save values into correct position
    temp[temp_keys[res.data[i]['assignedTo']]]['values'].push([res.data[i]['createdDate'], res.data[i]['count']]);
}
console.log(temp);
console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));
```

JSON Example Output:

```
[{"key":"0","values":[["23-07-2013","2"]]},{"key":"182398","values":[["01-08-2013","2"],["23-07-2013","2"],["24-07-2013","12"],["22-07-2013","1"],["30-07-2013","4"],["31-07-2013","19"]]},{"key":"185271","values":[["24-07-2013","2"],["23-07-2013","1"]]}]
```

Comment: Instead of of saving the array index in `temp_keys`, you could just save the object (that you add to the array) itself.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes i could, but i did not do that only because in question was wanted output as an array. If i create temp as object {} then i need to convert it into array later in order json.stringify would give me wanted result as an array. Also tought that mabye its easier to read in current way not sure tough.

Comment: No, I'm talking about `tmp_keys`. Instead of storing `id -> index` you could store `id -> obj` and then you could just do: `temp_keys[res.data[i]['assignedTo']]['values'].push([res.data[i]['createdDate'], res.data[i]['count']]);`, i.e. you avoid accessing both,  `temp` and `temp_keys`.

Comment: Thanks for this! But if the data source is not sorted by keys, you'll get duplicates with this code of yours. I was getting duplicate keys so rather than if (!temp_keys[res.data[i]['assignedTo']]) I used if (typeof temp_keys[res.data[i]['assignedTo']] == "undefined") and all was dandy.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the `cumulative_key` is in the wrong loop:

```
lastKey = res.data[0]['assignedTo'];
for(i in res.data) {
    if(res.data[i]['assignedTo'] != last) {
        cumulative_val += '{key:"'+res.data[i]['assignedTo']+'",values:'+time_val+'},';
    }
    time_val += "["+res.data[i]['createdDate']+","+res.data[i]['count']+"],";
}
```

You should think about manipulate real array object and then after make a json encoding.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Actually I have to do all in js not in php. 
But two issues are there first of all time_val are repeating whenever I am trying to print the value of cumulative_val outside of the for loop.
second thing is that all the date and count should be groupwise and group by assignedTo.

Comment: Then don't put [php] tag in your post if you're not talking about it :p Does your array is sorted by "assignedTo" values?

Comment: I would create appropriate class for this JSON packet, create assignment constructor and pack objects of this class in some data structure (array, for example).

Comment: No its not. It directly fetch from database. But I can do in a sorted order.

Comment: Try my updated code. May need some ajustments but the logic is here.

Comment: This is not valid JS, the result also not a valid JSON object, `JSON.parse()` fails to process it.

Answer (score 0):

use these functions

```
json_decode

get_object_vars
```

Comment: OP is using JavaScript, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
var _root = new Array();
        for (i in res.data) {
            for (k in res.data[i]) {
                var _child  = [res.data[i]['createdDate'], res.data[i]['count']];
                var _parent = [{"key":res.data[i]['assignedTo'], "values": _child}];
            }
           _root.push(_parent); 
        }
        var _JSON_ = JSON.stringify(_root);
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different solution just for the sake of variety

```js
let res = {
    "status": "Success", "data": [
        {"assignedTo": "185271", "createdDate": "23-07-2013", "count": "1"},
        {"assignedTo": "182398", "createdDate": "01-08-2013", "count": "2"},
        {"assignedTo": "182398", "createdDate": "23-07-2013", "count": "2"},
        {"assignedTo": "182398", "createdDate": "24-07-2013", "count": "12"},
        {"assignedTo": "185271", "createdDate": "24-07-2013", "count": "2"},
        {"assignedTo": "182398", "createdDate": "22-07-2013", "count": "1"},
        {"assignedTo": "0", "createdDate": "23-07-2013", "count": "2"},
        {"assignedTo": "182398", "createdDate": "30-07-2013", "count": "4"},
        {"assignedTo": "182398", "createdDate": "31-07-2013", "count": "19"},
        ]
};

let values = [];
let ctrl = '';
let interim = {};

for (const obj of res.data) {
    const id = obj.assignedTo;
    values = interim[obj.assignedTo] ? interim[obj.assignedTo].values : [];
    values.push([obj.createdDate, obj.count])
    interim[obj.assignedTo] = {"key": obj.assignedTo, "values": values};
    ctrl = ctrl !== id ? id : ctrl;
}

let reshaped = Object.values(interim);

console.log(JSON.stringify(reshaped, null, 0));
```

and the result is

```js
 [{"key": "0", "values": [["23-07-2013", "2"]]},
  {"key": "182398", "values": [["01-08-2013", "2"],
                               ["23-07-2013", "2"],
                               ["24-07-2013", "12"],
                               ["22-07-2013", "1"],
                               ["30-07-2013", "4"],
                               ["31-07-2013", "19"]]},
  {"key": "185271", "values": [["23-07-2013", "1"],
                               ["24-07-2013", "2"]]}
  ]
```

I "shuffled" the input data a bit just to avoid a mistake of assuming the data is always sorted... which I almost fell into twice while was writing up this snippet.